# Remove Hour, Minute and Second from Date() function in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, date

I'm getting yesterdays date with the following code:

```
  let yesterdaysDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: Date())
```

And when I run it it prints out:

```
2020-03-14 21:54:11 +0000
```

How do I just extract the 2020-03-14 and not the hour, minutes and seconds? Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "extract"? Do you only care about how it _prints_, or do you want the actual _date_ that has zero hours, minutes, and seconds?

Comment: There's no need to be rude; it's a very real question. People are often unclear about what they want from a date, because the underlaying date-time and the string representation to be shown to the user are very different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
let form = DateFormatter()
form.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd" 
print(form.string(from:yesterdaysDate))
```

Comment: Not my downvote but when working with fixed date formats you should always set the formatter locale to “en_US_POSIX” https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1480/_index.html

Comment: if you're working with fixed-format dates, you should first set the locale of the date formatter to something appropriate for your fixed format. In most cases the best locale to choose is "en_US_POSIX", a locale that's specifically designed to yield US English results regardless of both user and system preferences. "en_US_POSIX" is also invariant in time (if the US, at some point in the future, changes the way it formats dates, "en_US" will change to reflect the new behaviour, but "en_US_POSIX" will not), and between machines

Comment: ("en_US_POSIX" works the same on iOS as it does on OS X, and as it it does on other platforms).